# How would i convert this bat file to shell script for linux loading a java program

Tags: java, linux, shell, batch-file, jar

This is the bat file:

```
@echo off
"I:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin\java" -Xmx1300m -cp data/CompiledFiles;deps/poi.jar;deps/mysql.jar;deps/mina.jar;deps/slf4j.jar;deps/slf4j-nop.jar;deps/jython.jar;log4j-1.2.15.jar; server.Server
pause
```

What would the shell script equivalent be? This bat file loads up a java server program that should be compatible with linux but I am not good with shell script. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

In case you are fine with the default Java interepreter on the system:

```
#! /bin/sh
java -Xmx1300m -cp data/CompiledFiles;deps/poi.jar;deps/mysql.jar;deps/mina.jar;deps/slf4j.jar;deps/slf4j-nop.jar;deps/jython.jar;log4j-1.2.15.jar; server.Server
```

Otherwise:

```
#! /bin/sh
/path/to/executable/java -Xmx1300m -cp data/CompiledFiles;deps/poi.jar;deps/mysql.jar;deps/mina.jar;deps/slf4j.jar;deps/slf4j-nop.jar;deps/jython.jar;log4j-1.2.15.jar; server.Server
```

Answer (score 0):

should be very similar:

```
#!/bin/sh
java -Xmx1300m -cp data/CompiledFiles;deps/poi.jar;deps/mysql.jar;deps/mina.jar;deps/slf4j.jar;deps/slf4j-nop.jar;deps/jython.jar;log4j-1.2.15.jar; server.Server
read
```

the pause keeps the window open, I dont know if thats really intended, so maybe remove the 'read'